# Can't import using COPY in cassandra [protocol error]

Tags: copy

I am trying to import 209GB csv file into cassandra. But, I am getting below error,

ErrorMessage code=000a [Protocol error] message="Cannot decode string as UTF8: 'a00741031f26eca0272c274e272c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c302c2778272c274d272c2753656e736f72556e6465724d61696e74656e616e6365272c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c2735363734313266386438316465352e3434363638343739272c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c274e272c274e272c274e272c302c274e272c27323031362d30342d31342031323a34333a3035272c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c27323031362d30342d31342031323a34333a3035272c2741435f52454144494e47272c2735363734313761643735616666312e3533393537303831272c2745272c6e756c6c2c302c6e756c6c2c6e756c6c2c2732322d35352d38382d39392d36362d3333272c6e756c6c2c27372e33382729'; java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1">
Aborting import at record #32. Previously inserted records are still present, and some records after that may be present as well.

I checked record#32. No error found. When I repeated the import  again, it throws the same error at some other record#.  I am unable to fix the issue. Please help.